# Is there a way to compare the values of a Pandas DataFrame with the values of a second DataFrame?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, match

I have 2 Pandas Dataframes with 5 columns and about 1000 rows each (working with python3).
I'm interested in making a comparison between the first column in `df1` and the first column of `df2` as follows:

```
DF1
[index]   [col1]
1         "foobar"
2         "acksyn"
3         "foobaz"
4         "ackfin"
...       ...
```

```
DF2
[index]   [col1]
1         "old"
2         "fin"
3         "new"
4         "bar"
...       ...
```

What I want to achieve is this: for each row of `DF1`, if `DF1.col1` ends in any values of `DF2.col1`, drop the row.
In this example the resulting `DF1` should be:

```
DF1
[index]   [col1]
2         "acksyn"
3         "foobaz"
...       ...
```

(see `DF2` indexes 2 and 4 are the final part in `DF1` indexes 1 and 4)

---

I tried using an internally defined function like:

```
def check_presence(df1_col1, second_csv):
    for index, row in second_csv.iterrows():
        search_string = "(?P<first_group>^(" + some_string + "))(?P<the_rest>" + row["col1"] + "$)"
        if re.search(search_string, df1_col1):
            return True
    return False
```

and instructions with this format:
`indexes = csv[csv.col1.str.contains(some_regex, regex= True, na=False)].index`
but in both cases the python console complies about not being able to compare *non-string objects* with a string

---

What am I doing wrong? I can even try a solution after joining the 2 CSVs but I think I would need to do the same thing in the end
Thanks for patience, I'm new to python...

Comment: "" for each row of DF1, if DF1.col1 ends in any values of DF2.col1, drop the row.""  Do you know the number of values that DF1.col1 is matching with DF2.col1? Is it just the last 3 values of DF1.col1 that you're matching DF2.col1?

Comment: No, I don't know the exact number of each. The match has to be with the whole DF2.col1 values, not the last three. Those were an example

Comment: No problem - I have added a one-liner that should solve your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Possible Solution

> "" for each row of DF1, if DF1.col1 ends in any values of DF2.col1, drop the row.""

#### This is a one-liner if I understand properly:

```py
# Search for Substring
# Generate an "OR" statement with a join
# Drop if match. 
df[~df.col1.str.contains('|'.join(df2.col1.values))]
```

This will keep only the rows where DF2.Col1 is **NOT** found in DF1.Col1.

[pd.Series.str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)

Comment: Could it become something like: `df[~df1.col1.str.contains("$|".join(df2.col1.str) + "$", regex=True, na=False)]`? DF1 strings should *finish with* any of DF2 in order to be dropped

Comment: You could if there is added filtering value in doing so

Answer (score 1):

You will need to `join` your keywords in `df2` first if you want to use `str.contains` method.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': {0: 'foobar', 1: 'acksyn', 2: 'foobaz', 3: 'ackfin'}})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': {0: 'old', 1: 'fin', 2: 'new', 3: 'bar'}})

print (df["col1"].str.contains("|".join(df2["col1"])))

#
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
```

Answer (score 0):

Take your frames

```
frame1 =frame1=pd.DataFrame({"col1":["foobar","acksyn","foobaz","ackfin"]})
frame2=pd.DataFrame({"col1":["old","fin","new","bar"]})
```

Then

```
myList=frame2.col2.values
pattern='|'.join(myList)
```

Finally

```
 frame1["col2"]=frame1["col1"].str.contains(pattern)
frame1.loc[frame1["col2"]==True]
     col1  col2
0  foobar  True
3  ackfin  True
```