# Using startswith function to filter a list of urls

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, startswith

I have the following piece of code which extracts all links from a page and puts them in a list (`links=[]`), which is then passed to the function `filter_links()` .
I wish to filter out any links that are not from the same domain as the starting link, aka the first link in the list. This is what I have:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

start_url = "http://www.enzymebiosystems.org/"
r = requests.get(start_url)
html_content = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, features='lxml')
links = []
for tag in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    links.append(tag['href'])


def filter_links(links):
    filtered_links = []
    for link in links:
        if link.startswith(links[0]):
            filtered_links.append(link)
        return filtered_links


print(filter_links(links))
```

I have used the built-in startswith function, but its filtering out everything except the starting url.
Eventually I want to pass several different start urls through this program, so I need a generic way of filtering urls that are within the same domain as the starting url.I think I could use regex but this function should work too?

Comment: Print your links - most probably your initial link is not to the root of the linktargets site but has some params in it thatis not matched by any other link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import tldextract

start_url = "http://www.enzymebiosystems.org/"
r = requests.get(start_url)
html_content = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, features='lxml')
links = []
for tag in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    links.append(tag['href'])

def filter_links(links):
    ext = tldextract.extract(start_url)
    domain = ext.domain
    filtered_links = []
    for link in links:
        if domain in link:
            filtered_links.append(link)
    return filtered_links


print(filter_links(links))
```

**Note** :

1. You need to get that return statement out of the for loop. It is just returning the result after iterating over just one element and thus only the first item inside a list is only getting returned.
2. Use `tldextract` module to better extract the domain name from the urls. If you want to explicitly check whether the links starts with `links[0]`, it's up to you.

**Output** :

```
['http://enzymebiosystems.org', 'http://enzymebiosystems.org/', 'http://enzymebiosystems.org/leadership/about/', 'http://enzymebiosystems.org/leadership/directors-advisors/', 'http://enzymebiosystems.org/leadership/mission-values/', 'http://enzymebiosystems.org/leadership/marketing-strategy/', 'http://enzymebiosystems.org/leadership/business-strategy/', 'http://enzymebiosystems.org/technology/research/', 'http://enzymebiosystems.org/technology/manufacturer/', 'http://enzymebiosystems.org/recent-developments/', 'http://enzymebiosystems.org/investors-media/presentations-downloads/', 'http://enzymebiosystems.org/investors-media/press-releases/', 'http://enzymebiosystems.org/contact-us/', 'http://enzymebiosystems.org/leadership/about', 'http://enzymebiosystems.org/leadership/about', 'http://enzymebiosystems.org/leadership/marketing-strategy', 'http://enzymebiosystems.org/leadership/marketing-strategy', 'http://enzymebiosystems.org/contact-us', 'http://enzymebiosystems.org/contact-us', 'http://enzymebiosystems.org/view-sec-filings/', 'http://enzymebiosystems.org/view-sec-filings/', 'http://enzymebiosystems.org/unregistered-sale-of-equity-securities/', 'http://enzymebiosystems.org/unregistered-sale-of-equity-securities/', 'http://enzymebiosystems.org/enzymebiosystems-files-sec-form-8-k-change-in-directors-or-principal-officers/', 'http://enzymebiosystems.org/enzymebiosystems-files-sec-form-8-k-change-in-directors-or-principal-officers/', 'http://enzymebiosystems.org/form-10-q-for-enzymebiosystems/', 'http://enzymebiosystems.org/form-10-q-for-enzymebiosystems/', 'http://enzymebiosystems.org/technology/research/', 'http://enzymebiosystems.org/investors-media/presentations-downloads/', 'http://enzymebiosystems.org', 'http://enzymebiosystems.org/leadership/about/', 'http://enzymebiosystems.org/leadership/directors-advisors/', 'http://enzymebiosystems.org/leadership/mission-values/', 'http://enzymebiosystems.org/leadership/marketing-strategy/', 'http://enzymebiosystems.org/leadership/business-strategy/', 'http://enzymebiosystems.org/technology/research/', 'http://enzymebiosystems.org/technology/manufacturer/', 'http://enzymebiosystems.org/investors-media/news/', 'http://enzymebiosystems.org/investors-media/investor-relations/', 'http://enzymebiosystems.org/investors-media/press-releases/', 'http://enzymebiosystems.org/investors-media/stock-information/', 'http://enzymebiosystems.org/investors-media/presentations-downloads/', 'http://enzymebiosystems.org/contact-us']
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay so you made an indentation error in `filter_links(links)`. The function should be like this

```py
def filter_links(links):
    filtered_links = []
    for link in links:
        if link.startswith(links[0]):
            filtered_links.append(link)
    return filtered_links
```

Notice that in your code, you kept the return statement inside the for loop so, the for loop gets executed once and then returns the list. 

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

### Possible Solution

> What about if you kept all links which 'contain' the domain?

For example

```
import pandas as pd

links = []
for tag in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    links.append(tag['href'])

all_links = pd.DataFrame(links, columns=["Links"])
enzyme_df = all_links[all_links.Links.str.contains("enzymebiosystems")]

# results in a dataframe with links containing "enzymebiosystems".
```

If you want to search multiple domains, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59182982/7281271)